# How to disable peek windows at the left side of a screen?

Tags: windows-8-preview, v-studio-2011-preview

Is there a way to disable little preview windows that show up when I move mouse cursor to left edge of a screen?

It annoys the hell out of me. Everytime I need to click on vertical "Solution Explorer" tab in Visual Studio I click on preview window which throws me to Metro UI. What a horrible design.

Comment: Its pre-beta (alpha) software, hell yes its horrible!

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have no f* choice. We need to adopt our product to Win8 by the time of its release :(

Comment: I assume at some point there will be a RC release, you may have to wait until then to refine your product. Is there no support from Microsoft for W8 developers? I think the whole idea of the metro ui sucks, but its getting rammed down our throats like it or not, F'ing Apple started this dumbed down user interface with the ipad. Its going to turn the whole computer experience into a steaming pile of crap.

Comment: @Moab The feature made it into the RTM and is still horrible.  It's extremely jarring and quite easy to accidentally hit in a lot of applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now possible to turn this off in the Release Preview.  At least the top/left last window preview (which seems to be the most troublesome).

Not quite sure the best way to navigate to it, but you need to go to `PC Settings` > `General` > `App switching` and turn off the first option that reads `Allow switching between recent apps`.  As silly as the option is worded, don't worry, it doesn't disable ALT+TAB or anything.

I got there from the home (metro) screen:
 - Click your name on the top right
 - Click change account picture
 - Click General on the left

And you're there...

**ETA**: This has a side effect that you may or may not want.  I realized after turning it off that I could no longer ALT+TAB to Metro apps.  That might be a good thing for some people, but it sure would be nice if there were two separate options (1 to turn off the hot corner, and the other to turn off alt+tabbing).

Answer (score 0):

The "go back" UI will only show up when the mouse pointer is placed in the extreme upper-left corner.  Only one thumbnail will show.  While shown, sliding the mouse pointer down the left edge will reveal more thumbnails, this is known as the "switcher UI".